# How can I print an inverted or upside down parallelogram in java?

Tags: java

I am new to java and my professor has assigned us to print different shapes using method classes that ultimately form shapes by using the for loop. I have made a parallelogram regularly, but I am confused to how I would go about making an inverse parallelogram. If this question has been asked before, i am sorry for wasting your time, as i couldn't find anything that could fully help me achieve my results.

My goal is to make an right arrow by combining the regular and the inversed parallelogram

Here is what I have so far: PLEASE KEEP IN MIND, that this is part of a larger program so i have just added the necessary lines of code.

```
 public class GeoImage { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int m=5, n=10;
    char star = '*';

 System.out.println("Parallogram");
 String p = Parallogram(m, n, star);//Parallogram

    static String Parallogram(int x, int y, char output){
    String parallogram = "";
       for (int a = 0; a<x; a++){
       parallogram = parallogram + output;
       }//for loop

          for(int b = 0; b<x; b++){
          System.out.println(parallogram);
          parallogram = " " + parallogram;          
          }//for loop

      return "parallogram";
     }//parallogram
```

My out put looks like this:

```
*****
 *****
  *****
   *****
    *****
```

I would like something like this:

```
    *****
   *****
  *****
 *****
*****
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first for loop would work fine for the inverse parallelogram, then create an array of strings with the size of x-1. Where the each index would hold x-1, x-2 ... 1 space. Then print out the String[i] + output.

```
String[] spaces = new String[x-1];
for(int i = 0; i < x; x++){
    spaces[i] = "";
    for(int j = 1; j < x; j++){
        spaces[j] += " "; //Adds another space to the string
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks can you elaborate your answer some more, I am not filimiar with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going from 0 to x when incrementing b, you just have to go from x to 0.

Change the second for loop to:

```
for(int b = x; b>0; b--){
    System.out.println(parallogram);
    parallogram = " " + parallogram;          
}//for loop
```